# issue with setThemingColor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Having some issues with setThemingColor not really producing coloured output.

```
viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.setThemingColor(
          7714,
          new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1)
        );
```

That dbId is a valid id in my model, I've tried to clear the colours before but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a newer version of Threejs that I installed through an ES module, using the forge viewer version of Threejs instead it works perfectly. It seems even matching the revision level to the one used by forge doesn't resolve it, probably they are using a customised version.

Comment: I was going to ask you the same question that you've answered yourself ;) - always use the THREE.js library that comes bundled with Viewer